# Jitsi-meet android released app crash when startup

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

The released app crash when startup without any prompts.

1. I cloned the git repo `jitsi/jitsi-meet`.
2. Run `npm install`. There is an mistake of SASS. Then I changed the version of SASS to 'latest'.
3. Remove `node-modules` dir and run `npm cache clean --force`.
4. Run `npm install`.
5. Run `make`.
6. Generate android cert to `android/app/` and change the `build.gradle` to apply the cert.
7. Run `./gradlew assembleRelease` in `android/`.
8. Run `./gradlew installRelease`.

I also try the app on emulator and it crash too.

Android SDK 26
build tool 26.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index.android.bundle` is missing in released app. Try follow command:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

It works fine, but there is an another issue: All icons are missing.

UPDATE: Fix icons missing,[here](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/1961#issuecomment-379638115).

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix the icons issue?

Comment: @Hahn Updated, you can try it.

Comment: Thanks! will try it out!

Comment: @Hahn How about it going? I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: I think it worked for me. However, I moved on from the project, so don't have access to it atm.

Comment: @leili Would you be so kind to list down the step by step process with commands to build android app? I am new to android development. I want to host my own jitsi meet server and create android app.

Comment: Sorry, really I forgot how to build it. I'm a frontend web developer in fact. You can follow the guide of jitsi-meet and it works generally. @Umair

Comment: i am facing this issue in flutter any idea about it?